# Wordpress XML Media Import with HTTP Authentication

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, http-authentication

I'm trying to use the wordpress-importer plugin to import an xml file exported from another wordpress blog which happens to have HTTP authentication on it.

As is, when I run the import, media files are failing with:

```
Failed to import Media “Image replace”: Remote server returned error response 401 Unauthorized
```

If I do a find and replace in the XML file on the URI to be

```
username:password@blogtoimportfrom.com
```

I get

```
Failed to import Media “Image replace”: Remote server did not respond
```

Should I be more selective with my find / replace?  Or is there some other way to provide the Auth credentials?

TIA,
Billy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.  I did a find and replace on all occurrences of the URI with the username / password version.

I then had to modify one line of Wordpress code.  In

```
wp-includes/http.php
```

I changed this method:

```
function wp_safe_remote_request( $url, $args = array() ) {
        $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = true;
        $http = _wp_http_get_object();
        return $http->request( $url, $args );
}
```

to read

```
function wp_safe_remote_request( $url, $args = array() ) {
        $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;   // <------- just this line
        $http = _wp_http_get_object();
        return $http->request( $url, $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use headers to auth because wp was mangling the auth in the url.

In wordpress-importer.php...

```
$args_ = array(
            'timeout' => 300,
            'stream' => true,
            'filename' => $upload['file'],
            'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:pass'))
    );

$remote_response = wp_safe_remote_get( $url,  $args_);
```